# Networked/offline Message routing

Tags: c#, .net, networking, design-patterns

I am working on rewriting a MUD based game engine of mine with one of the primary goals being makin it a bit more modular, decoupling the components. One of the things I've hit a wall with is distributing messages.

When a user sets the engine to run as a MMO, then all communication is done through the server. Objects send and receive messages, execute commands and receive data from the environment through their network Socket.

The revised version of the engine will support single player offline games. Are there patterns in place that I can use for routing messages/data through a central location that can redirect as needed between the server or local client? I don't want to litter the engine with conditional statements to check if if is networked or not. I'd rather have a dispatcher of some kind that handles this communication.

If anyone could point me in the right direction to achieve this I'd appreciate it!

*edit:* I have been working hard at keeping the engine pretty abstract. I make heavy use of the factory pattern, generics and repositories to prevent tight coupling. I'm wanting to continue that approach with the networking aspect. In 90% of the cases, networked communication will be caused by a command sent from the clients telnet client. So handling receiving their commands and handling based on network state is straight forward. The tricky part comes within the game loop where I have to broadcast messages sent from numerous objects back to the client. All network enabled objects implement a IServerObject interface so the server knows what objects it can and can't communicate with. I'm thinking a central dispatching system makes sense but not sure if there is a pattern I can follow to help guide me.

Comment: You can always create an interface called IClient that has two subclasses, LocalClient and RemoteClient. LocalClient would redirect the messages to the internal message queue, RemoteClient would broadcast them to other players.

You would want to not encode or decode messages in this case, so your LocalClient.Send(Message) method would just push the message back into the event queue. I'll comment with an example after my loL match

Comment: Thanks @Dan! I haven't thought of an event queue either. I should mention that while networked, all of the clients are instanced and managed asynchronously.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference, as I said all you would do is make a new interface that you could marry the local and remote clients together and then derive from those

Comment: Instead of the server looping through each object in the game loop iteration and invoking an update method, clients send direct to the server through a delegate as a result of a Command (walk, look etc) object being called. When an event (such as weather changing or day/night transition) needs to be broadcasted to users, then a world object broadcasts (again an async action) to all players. Rather than performing client updates in each iteration of the game loop.  Would I still take an event queue approach? Any patterns or examples that I can use to implement an event queue?

Comment: I would use the Observer pattern as I noted in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**

This is most definitely not the best way of doing it but it is the one that requires the least effort. In my opinion the server should not be aware of it is broadcasting to a single client or multiple remote ones as to the server all clients are remote. You should just simply not accept any connections that aren't sourced locally IMO

```
/// <summary>
/// A wrapper around a client instance that is interested in
/// the game events. It is observable, and when you observe the
/// client, you can subscribe to the messages we receive from that
/// client.
/// </summary>
public interface IClient : IObservable<IMessage>, IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Send the client a message.
    /// The client is responsible for encoding
    /// or decoding the message as necessary
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    void Send(IMessage message);
}

/// <summary>
/// Some information that can be sent to either a remote
/// client or a local client. This could be as simple as
/// EventArgs, just make sure you can write a decoder/encoder
/// for each of the types. The message types should derive
/// from this interface
/// </summary>
public interface IMessage
{

}

/// <summary>
/// A class that can serialize or deserialize messages
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TSerializedType"></typeparam>
public interface IMessageSerializer<TSerializedType>
{
    TSerializedType Encode(IMessage message);

    IMessage Decode(TSerializedType serialized);
}

/// <summary>
/// This is a client located at a remote location (i.e,
/// not at this server and we're connecting to it via a Tcp
/// connection)
/// </summary>
public class RemoteClient : IClient
{
    private readonly TcpClient _client;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the Remote client.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="client">The underlying .NET connection</param>
    /// <param name="serializer">The instance of IMessageSerializer that can
    /// serialize or deserialize messages</param>
    public RemoteClient(TcpClient client, IMessageSerializer serializer)
    {
        ....
    }

    public void Send(IMessage message)
    {
        var serialized = serializer.Encode(message);
        client.Write(serialized);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This is the class you would use if you were connecting
/// to no one and just wanted to route messages back to yourself
/// </summary>
public class LocalClient : IClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the local client
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="messageQueue">An observer that is listening for messages.
    /// This is our message queue and it should be pointing at someone who
    /// is interested in consuming the messages (the game UI for example)</param>
    public LocalClient(IObserver<IMessage> messageQueue)
    {
    }

    public void Send(IMessage message)
    {
        messageQueue.OnNext(message);
    }
}
```

This is similar to the implementation I use in my Minecraft server. You would create a different type of client depending on whether you are interested in sending to remote clients or not. You could one step further and skip the `LocalClient` approach and just broadcast to the `IObserver<IMessage>` instead.

The intended usage is that you would create a `LocalClient` instead of `RemoteClient`s and broadcast to that instead, which will push the message you just told the `LocalClient` to receive to an `IObserver<IMessage>` - which should be the party that consumes events in your server.

You would change between `LocalClient` and `RemoteClient` by creating an `IClientFactory`, then deriving that to create a `LocalClientFactory` and `RemoteClientFactory` (omitted for brevity) and use dependency injection to alter what kind of client factory you use.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a good starting point for it. I'll have to learn how to implement DI, I'm familiar with the concept and understand what it is, but have yet to use it in any of my applications.

Comment: DI can be as simple as just letting a constructor define what it's dependencies are.. you don't have to use a DI framework. `RemoteClient` in my example is using DI.

Comment: Is it bad practice to have a single object be both IObservable and IObserver? So the server will want to listen for notifications sent by an object (such as a NPC) while at the same time posting notifications for other objects (such as clients).

Comment: You can use `ISubject<T>` for that, but imo that is violation of SRP. Instead pass an `IObserver<T>` into the constructor and notify that.

Comment: Just for clarity sake, if an object (such as an NPC) needs to  notify the server that its location has changed, it must be given the server as an `IObserver` in its constructor (or even a method), which it will post to and the Server will `subscribe` to NPC, so that it can send notifications to it?

Comment: In that case I would make the NPC be an observable and have the NPC controller subscribe to it (in an MVC architecture)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if a MVC architecture is the approach I would want to go. Since the engine is UI agnostic, and will eventually end up being used by both a MVVM and a MVC UI based app when finished. Perhaps implementing [the Mediator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) is the approach I should go for this? A mediator between NPC (and other `IObservable` objects that are two way) and the server. Mediator can register for events in the `IObservable` and post them back to the server.

Comment: Well, the view in MVC is not just something visible.. The View in my Minecraft server is the socket, for example. It's up to you after all :)